# How can I select all a with an attribute that is NOT containing a word?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm currently using jQuery to show or hide elements based on what the worktype attribute is containing.

I need to know how can I select the opposite of :

```
$("a[worktype*="+worktype+"]")
```

*= selects all a tags where the attribute worktype is containing the value of worktype

I want to do the opposite, how can I select all a tags where the attribute worktype is not containing the value of the worktype variable ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the asterisk (*) with an exclamation point (!)? https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: Yes, but != returns false if it's different, i want it to return false if it's not containing something

Comment: Wat? `not containing something` or `not containing the value of the worktype variable`? https://jsfiddle.net/9280wjyb/

Comment: @mark.hch https://jsfiddle.net/9280wjyb/1/. OP wants `some-prod` and `prod-something-else` to be treated same as `prod`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thank you for the clarification. I try, but sometimes it's just hard to evaluate desire. I know you don't want it anymore, OP, and I know Andrei got your back already, but `$('a:not([worktype*="' + worktype + '"])` https://jsfiddle.net/9280wjyb/2/

Comment: @mark.hch I think that's what OP wanted all along, but until you haven't showed it I didn't understand that's what they wanted. :)

Comment: @mark.hch: I would still recommend putting that in an answer, since it's actually an answer. If you'd rather not, though (e.g. don't want to get rep for it), I can do that for you. I'm kinda starved of [jquery-selectors] answers for the tag badge anyways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all anchors with worktype and check if "worktype" is anywhere to be found in the attribute:

```js
$("a[worktype]").each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('worktype').indexOf('worktype') === -1) {
    $(this).css({color:'red'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a worktype="normal">no worktype</a><br />
<a worktype="some worktype">worktype</a><br />
<a>no worktype attribute</a><br />
<a worktype="worktype">worktype</a>
```

jQuery is still JavaScript.

Comment: It works perfectly, but I think I'm gonna use something else, because it doesn't do what I thought it would do

Comment: @Yasboy, if you tell me what you want I can tell you how to achieve it. It's virtual space, so anything is possible.

Comment: @Yash, if you want to select all anchors not having the contents of `worktype` variable inside their `worktype` attribute, just replace `indexOf('worktype')` with `indexOf(worktype)` in the script above.

Comment: well I uploaded my project on https://echinoid-resistance.000webhostapp.com/ I want to animate the work tiles at the bottom of the page, when we click on a tag (like "webdesign" or "3danimation"). I know it's not possible to animate the display proprety in CSS, so maybe there is an other way to do this. I wanted to make the tiles fade out, and slide the remaining tiles so they can be next to each other, and do the opposite when tiles appear but I have absolutely no idea how I can do that

Comment: That's not a trivial task, @Yasboy. In order to do this you need a `masonry`-like script to display your tiles, which uses `position:absolute`. After changing the filters, you need to recalculate position of each element and animate them from current position to the new one. By far, the easiest way to achieve it is to use [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/), as all you have to do is call `.masorny()` again on your collection after the filter changes.

Comment: thanks for your help mate ! I think I'm gonna replace my tile system with this https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ because it what I'm expecting